# KeystoneJS with letsencrypt - certificate files required

Tags: https, lets-encrypt, keystonejs

I am following this tutorial [Let’s Encrypt KeystoneJS!](https://medium.com/keystone-js/lets-encrypt-keystonejs-81fd55db9a3d) in an attempt to get letsencrypt working on my KeystoneJS project.

However, when I start the server I am getting the error:

`SSL Not Started: Invalid SSL Configuration (certificate files required)`

I've generated the standalone certificate with certbot to the directory `/home/example/letenscrypt` resulting in:

```
- accounts
- csr
- keys
- letsencrypt.log
- renewal
- renewal-hooks
```

I've also tried defining the configdir in my keystone init:

```
keystone.init({
...
  letsencrypt: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') && {
    email: 'admin@myapp.com',
    domains: ['www.myapp.com', 'myapp.com'],
    register: true,
    tos: true,
    configDir: '/home/example/letsencrypt'
  },
...
})
```

I've also tried `configDir: '/home/example/letsencrypt/keys'` but I always get the same error, I'm wondering what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue was the `NODE_ENV` wasn't correctly set to `production`. Setting it properly in my `.env` solved this issue (but raised another unfortunately with an invalid certificate being generated)

https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/Deployment-Checklist